Constructing a subsequence of $\{ f_k\} \subseteq L^p(\Omega)$ that satisfies these two properties
Let $1 <p< \infty$ and $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $T : D(T) \subseteq L^p(\Omega) \to L^p(\Omega)$ is a linear operator defined on a subset $D(T)$ of $L^p(\Omega)$. Assume that $\{ f_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of functions in $L^p(\Omega)$ that converges to a function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ in $L^p$ and such that $T(f_k)$ converges to a function $w$ in $L^p$.
Since the convergence of a sequence in $L^p$ implies pointwise convergence (almost everywhere) of a subsequence and since $f_k \to f$ in $L^p$, then there exists a subsequence $f_{k_n}$ of $ \{ f_k \}$ that converges to $f$ pointwise (almost everywhere). Also, since $T(f_k) \to w$ in $L^p$, there exists a subsequene $f'_{k_n}$ of $\{ f_k \}$ such that $T(f'_{k_n})$ converges pointwise (a.e) to $w$. I want to argue that, without loss of generality, we can assume that both subsequences $\{f_{k_n} \}$ and $\{f'_{k_n}\}$ are the same sequence (since I believe that, as both are subsequences of $\{f_k\}$, we could construct a subsequence that satisfies both properties). However, I am having trouble being able to justify this rigorously. How could I justify that both subsequences can actually be the same?

First, you can choose a subsequence such that $\{f_{k_n}\}$ converges pointwise and afterwards you select a subsequence of this subsequence, such that also $\{T(f_{k_{n_l}})\}$ converges pointwise.
Note that any subsequence of a subsequence is also a subsequence.

One you have extracted a subsequence $\left(f_{\varphi(k)}\right)$ such that $f_{\varphi(k)}\to f$ pointwise (where $\varphi\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is increasing, use that $\left(Tf_{\varphi(k)}\right)$ converges in $\mathbb L^p$ to $w$. Extract a further subsequence by finding an increasing $\psi\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $\left(Tf_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right)$ converges pointwise to $w$. We still have the pointwise convergence of $\left( f_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right)$ a it is a subsequence of $\left(f_{\varphi(k)}\right)$.
